# ImportError: No module named builtins - Google App Engine Standard - Django - Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-app-engine, built-in

I'm trying to deploy an application and this error keeps coming up. I am using the commands below in my views/models/form/settings.py, in order to use the same code I did for Python 3.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from builtins import (bytes, str, open, super, range,
                  zip, round, input, int, pow, object)
```

I've already installed the library:future==0.16.0 on my requirements-vendor.txt

On localhost I can run it, using a Conda Env (python 2.7) but the deployment on GAE(standard) I got the 500 Server Error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hi, thank you for the answer! In fact this was correctly configured, I had the folder `lib` and the `appengine_config.py` was exactly like the recommend by you and the tutorial page of Google. However I ended moving to Flexible Env. I tried to test again on Standard but I've already made a lot of changes in the project and some other errors came up, so I can't deploy there anymore. On flexenv everything works fine. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

App Engine Standard does not actually depends on a requirements.txt file for using third-party libraries, that's the case for [App Engine Flexbile](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries)

If you want to use a third-party library which is not in the list of already built-in libraries ([this list](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27)) ,as in this case is [future](https://pypi.org/project/future/), you need to follow the [Using third-party libraries for App Engine Standard docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27), which was mentioned by @snakecharmerb. Do the following n the same folder where you have your app.yaml file:

1. Create a directory where your third-party-libraries will be stored:

   `mkdir lib`
2. Install library on the created folder:

   `pip install -t lib future==0.16.0`
3. Create file named `appengine_config.py` and add the following two lines to the file:

   `from google.appengine.ext import vendor`

   `vendor.add('lib')`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! In fact this was correctly configured, I had the folder `lib` and the `appengine_config.py` was exactly like the recommend by you and the tutorial page of Google. However I ended moving to Flexible Env. I tried to test again on Standard but I've already made a lot of changes in the project and some other errors came up, so I can't deploy there anymore. On flexenv everything works fine. Thank you for the help!